# process null dates with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I need to process date strings with moment.js such that blank dates are accepted. Something like this:

```
if ((moment().isAfter(exDate))) or (moment(null)) {}
```

EXISTING CODE

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>

var exDate = moment(cccr_mems[i].cccrEXP, 'YYYY.MM.DD');
if (moment().isAfter(exDate)) {
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the && or || operators depending on which you need? `if ((moment().isAfter(exDate))) && (moment(null)) {}`

Comment: No, some expiration dates are the past, some in the future, and some are just blank.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused in getting what you want to achieve. So you want to check if an expiration date is blank before using it in the moment object?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay so you would first check if the date is null then do your moment logic i.e. `if(exDate != null) { moment exDate stuff }`. You might also have to check for empty string ("") depending on how your date variable works if empty.

Comment: solved it. Just made the default color before the if statement like so: $(ele).css('color', "#A3005B").css('font-weight', "bold");